# My compiler doesn't find the gazebo libraries

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, include, ros, gazebo-simu

I don't understand why, but my compile, visual studio code, Can't find gazebo libraries and make me an error, don't compile. In this case I'm using this libraries (all make and error):

```
#include <ignition math="" pose3.hh="">

#include "gazebo/physics/physics.hh"

#include "gazebo/common/common.hh"

#include "gazebo/gazebo.hh"
```

I've also use another compiler, KDevelop and the same error.

I have installed properly gazebo, and I've try with the vcpkg of visual studio but this item can not be installed in my mchine, I don't know why neither. I'm desesperated.

If anyone could help me, thanks.

Comment: Under the C/C++ Property Pages you should be able to specify additional include directories. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/c-cpp-prop-page?view=vs-2019

Comment: Also the use of quotes in your include path indicates that the compiler should look in the same folder as this `cpp` file. Do you have  a `gazebo/gazebo.hh` file in the current `cpp` file's directory?

Comment: I should have the libraries, it supose to be add when i install gazebo. Doesn't it?

Comment: I have no idea what your gazebo installation looks like. You have a directory which contains the `.cpp` file you're trying to compile. Go to that directory. Is there a directory in that directory called "gazebo"? Does the gazebo directory have a file called "gazebo.hh"? If not, then you can't include it this way.